# ER Diagram - How to write the schema for a recursive relationship with an attribute

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram

If I have an ER Diagram as such:
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fCOx.png)

How would I express this in a relational schema?